# Proguard gives errors with AWS SDK for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-proguard

In my Android app, I use some libs of Amazon:

- **aws-android-sdk-cognito-2.2.2.jar**,
- **aws-android-sdk-core-2.2.2.jar**,
- **aws-android-sdk-ddb-2.2.2.jar**,
- **aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper-2.2.2.jar**,
- **aws-android-sdk-sns-2.2.2.jar**,
- **aws-android-sdk-s3-2.2.2.jar**

When I export apk file with Proguard enabled and empty file proguard-project.txt I got these errors:

```
    [2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: 
    com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.GetQueueAttributesRequest
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.GetQueueAttributesRequest
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueAttributeName
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueAttributeName
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueAttributeName
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.GetQueueAttributesRequest
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.GetQueueAttributesResult
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.GetQueueAttributesResult
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueAttributeName
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SetQueueAttributesRequest
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SetQueueAttributesRequest
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.services.sns.util.Topics: can't find referenced class com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$1: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonReader: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: com.amazonaws.util.json.JacksonFactory$JacksonWriter: can't find referenced class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] Warning: there were 78 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-09-11 09:30:32 - MainActivity]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Please help me how to configure Proguard in this situation!

**EDIT: I use Eclipse.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the dependencies which the aws android sdk depends on.

If you are using gradle, instead of getting the jar by yourself, you should import it like this, which gradle would handle the transitive dependencies for you. Like this:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
```

setup guide of AWS
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html

If you are using Eclipse, you have to find the library yourself. You are missing `aws sqs` and `jackson`

Comment: I use Eclipse. Do you mean I have to find the jar files for aws sqs and jackson? My app works normally in debug. I got problems while export apk.

Comment: If you are sure this part of code is not used by your program indirectly, you may also add `-dontwarn com.amazonaws.**` to your proguard config.

Comment: If you want the dependencies to be complete, you have to find the jar files from web manually as you use Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm facing another problems. I can export file apk. But when app run, I got DynamoDbMapper exception: No method annotated with interface `com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey` for class. In my app I have a class which is mapped with a table of dynamodb.

Comment: This should be a completely different issue, please start a new question

Answer (score 15):

These warnings are due to missing class references. The way the SDK is packaged may cause warnings during proguard. However, these unresolved classes have no impact to the SDK. You can safely ignore them. Here is a minimal proguard configure to suppress them.

```
-keep class com.amazonaws.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.amazonaws.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.amazonaws.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**
```

See [Proguard's trouble shooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) for more details.

Comment: After adding your code, Eclipse lets me to export apk file. But it crashes when I run app from apk.

Comment: See revised proguard config. I suggest you keep all classes from the SDK.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this did not work for me.  Is the above working for anyone?

Comment: nvm, I got it working by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32521563/dynamodbmapperexception-no-method-annotated)