# DynamoDbMapperException: No method annotated?

Tags: android, proguard, amazon-dynamodb

In my android app, I use DynamoDb. I create a class, which is mapped with a table of database. App runs normally in debug. But if I export apk and run app, I get the DynamoDbMapperException:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMappingException: No method annotated with interface com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey for class class com.example.myclass.
```

I use Eclipse and proguard to export apk. I guess proguard causes the problem, because the apk without proguard works fine.
Here is my Proguard config:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.example.myclass
```

Please help me! I don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a DynamoDB table?

You need to have a hash key for the class, you should annotate the field with `@DynamoDBHashKey`, do you accidentally annotated it as `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey`? If so, you should change it back.

A similar reference can be found here

[Android Amazon DynamoDb error in basic action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556023/android-amazon-dynamodb-error-in-basic-action)

Edit:
Try chaning

```
-keep public class com.example.myclass
```

to

```
-keep public class com.example.myclass {
    *;
}
```

Comment: I do have a DynamoDbHashKey. My class works normally in debug. Only after export apk file I got the errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found out the answer too. Your answer is correct. Does the { *;} part allow to keep the variables and the methods inside class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can specify <fields> instead of `*` if you want fields only, you can reference to Proguard document for more details.